# docusign soap api One or both of Username and Password are invalid

Tags: docusignapi

i am using Docusign SOAP API method (Web Service : demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/dsapi.asmx) to create and send envelope.

Recently i got "One or both of Username and Password are invalid" Error, when my app tried to create and send envelope.

Following is the header for SOAP Request:

```
SOAPAction: "http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0/CreateAndSendEnvelope" VsDebuggerCausalityData: uIDPozOi+3I3/mdOnS6+lQqMROgAAAAAVxC5JHGKHE6fvR8BvZpHUHNpw/BcjtJIjk7zIhUkl2kACQAA X-DocuSign-Authentication: <DocuSignCredentials><Username>{Mine E-mail id}</Username><Password>{Password}</Password><IntegratorKey>{Mine Integrated Key}</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>
```

I double check the credentials (that i set with this request) and all relative information (i.e. Recipient, tabs and document information) w.r.t to the envelope that i wish to create but still i got this error.

Comment: Do you have multiple accounts and are maybe using the wrong account or Integrator Key?  Also do the credentials that you are trying work successfully if you test through the [API Explorer](http://iodocs.docusign.com/) tool?  Even though that tool is for REST and not SOAP your same credentials will work with both APIs, if they are valid.

Comment: I have only one account and i also check my credentials on API Explorer tool.

Comment: Not sure why you receiving this if the credentials are right.  At this point to debug I recommend you create a SOAP trace of the raw request your code is sending out, and edit your question and add that in so we can have a look, just remove your password, integrator key and email before posting.